# What type of SSL Certificate do I need for a HMail Server?

Tags: ssl, email-server, azure

I run HMail (Mail Server) on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine. I have several domains for email (8) in this single HMail / VM.

What type of SSL Certificate should I be buying?

What confuses me is that some SSL's say they cover 1 domain, but does that mean the 1 domain is my Mail Server, or is the 1 domain an individual email domain within HMail?

I am looking to move my main email over soon, but I want to get SSL first, confused about the options in this use case.

Thanks! Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single domain is the domain you access the web server, so if give each domain it's own web access URL, you will need multiple (UCC) Domains, one for each domain, like https://webmail.example.com and https://webmail.example.org

The same would apply if you separate service names, IMAPS.example.org and SMTP.example.org, these are 2 seperate domains, now imaps is more important, because it is SSL whereas SMTP should be using TLS (STARTTLS) and most email clients are more accepting of mis-matched or non-trusted SSLs in TLS but not when wrapping services in SSL (like IMAPS)

If you use mail.example.com for everything, then you only need an SSL for mail.example.com (recommended).

If all users access email via the same URL, you only need 1 domain SSL.

Also if you want to support Mutual TLS (encryption in email transit between servers), your ehlo domain name, should also match your mail server's hostname and the SSL domain name.

I would also disable SSLv3 and SSLv2 in the [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_ssltls) settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will not be front facing (IE Webmail) - so not accessed in a browser. Just using IMAP/SMTP from mail clients so using the same web server name in the configuration of this

Comment: Added to my answer for added clarity.